# UpdatePanel wrapped around a user control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, user-controls

I have a user control which contains some buttons and a placeholder.  Those buttons cause controls to be added/removed from placeholder.  Everything works fine.

Now I want to put this user control in a page, and wrap it in an updatepanel like so:

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ChildrenAsTriggers="true" ID="UpdatePanelFoo" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <grid:tablegrid ID="tablegrid_chapters" runat="server" SomeProperty="bar" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I run the page, it's still doing a full postback when I hit one of the buttons inside the user control.  What am I doing wrong, and how can I remedy this?

Update:

```
protected void Page_Init()
{
    ScriptManager scr = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
    Response.Write("EnablePartialRendering: " + scr.EnablePartialRendering);
}
```

Outputs "EnablePartialRendering: true"

Comment: Can you post the code that adds controls to the placeholder, and say which one you are clicking that's causing a full postback?

Comment: kinda long so here it is: http://pastebin.com/m27ee8069 - there is a placeholder, and two buttons, pressing either button causes a full postback

Comment: btw, "SomeProperty" in my sample above is "UserControlPath" in the pastebin code

Comment: @mgroves: can you add the aspx markup to that? Also what are you clicking that gives the full postback, `btn_add`?

Comment: There's not much to it: http://pastebin.org/83758

Comment: And yes, btn_add or btn_del will cause a full postback

Comment: I've updated the answer below, hopefully this will work for you...let me know in an @reply or answer comment if it doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have `EnablePartialRendering=true` on your `ScriptManager` in the page.

### Update

It looks like your UserControl has no events to be looking for...you have 2 options here.  Move the `UpdatePanel` inside the UserControl .ascx so it can see the button events as children to rig up or add an event for it to see, to do that try something like this:

```
    public event EventHandler Click;

    void btn_del_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (NumberOfRowControls > 0)
        {
            var rowToWhack = panel_rows.Controls.Children().Single(x => x.ID == "myrow" + (NumberOfRowControls - 1));
            panel_rows.Controls.Remove(rowToWhack);
            NumberOfRowControls--;
        }
        if(Click != null) Click(this, e);
    }

    void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var row = NewRow(NumberOfRowControls);
        panel_rows.Controls.Add(row);
        if(Click != null) Click(this, e);
    }
```

And update the UpdatePanel to be looking for it:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelFoo" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <grid:tablegrid ID="tablegrid_chapters" runat="server" SomeProperty="bar" />
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tablegrid_chapters" EventName="Click">
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Woo, making progress.  Now it works, one time.  I click again and I get a javascript error.

Comment: @mgroves: Excellent...if you run into another problem just follow-up with a comment

Comment: I will--you've been super helpful, I wish I could give you more points.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you add a ScriptManager as well to the page, otherwise there's no UpdatePanel functionality.

Comment: Not having the ScriptManager would result in an error that is not described.